# how to ignore eclipse errors in PHP file

Tags: php, eclipse, wordpress

I get 600 warnings in eclipse for various attributes.

```
Attribute (cellpadding) is obsolete. 
Its use is discouraged in HTML5 documents.  meta-boxes.php  
/project/wp-admin/includes  line 1142   HTML Problem
```

I have been to

```
Settings/Preferences/Web/Html Files/Validation
```

I have set everything to ignore, and added the attributes?
Is this a bug?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not really a solution, but using the [Aptana Studio plugin](http://www.aptana.com/) will not complain about `cellpadding`.

[image: php editor]